# how to make multiple validation using validationEngine

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation-engine

How to use validationEngine to validate different events on the form?
when you load the div that contains the response the new ajax button does not work validationEngine

```
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Ingresar1"/>

$("#formulario").validationEngine({
    success : function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../modulo2/catalogo_procesos_modulo2.php",
            data: "proceso=radicacion&oper=consultar&"+$('form').serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                $("#cargar_orden").html(data);  
            }                         
        })
    }, 
    failure : function() {
    } 
});

//load...
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Ingresar2"/>
```

Clicking again will not make the validation

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#formulario").validationEngine({
validationEventTriggers:"click",    
unbindEngine:false,
success: function(data){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",                           
    url: "../modulo2/catalogo_procesos_modulo2.php",
    data: "proceso=radicacion&oper=consultar&"+$('form').serialize(),                                
    success: function(data){                            
        if(data=='0'){
            alert("El numero de orden ya fue ingresado en el sistema")                                                                              
        }   else{                         
            $("#cargar_orden").html(data);          
        }               
    }                         
    })   
}   
});
```

botton1

```
<input class="submit" type="submit" id="consultar_orden" value="Consultar orden" />
```

botton2

```
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Ingresar"/>
```